# Issue accessing NiFi UI

Tags: apache-nifi

I've set up NiFi with homebrew and when it's up and running, I cannot access the UI. It looks like, by all means, NiFi is running fine according to "nifi status", but I can't access the UI in the browser. All that I see is this:

[image]

Any tips on how I might be able to remedy this?

Comment: have a look at this - https://bryanbende.com/development/2021/07/19/apache-nifi-1-14-0-secure-by-default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NiFi is now HTTPS by default. You are trying to access via HTTP.

Accessing NiFi with HTTP on the HTTPS port (This will FAIL)
[image]

Accessing NiFI with HTTPS on the HTTPS port (This will SUCCEED)
[image]

Comment: unfortunately, that is what i get when trying to access via HTTPS

Comment: Are you going to https://<address>:8443? The secure port is 8443 not 8080

Comment: I am, yes. I did everything according to the Nifi documentation. Everything appears to be set up correctly, I'm just not getting the actual UI, just jumbled symbols, not even an error message.

Comment: I have added screenshots demonstrating reproducing exactly your error. You must include https:// in the start of your URL.